# Dynamically grow user selection when they have selected "all"

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have users with multiple email preferences and I want to *grow* their preference selection  when new preference options are added if they have selected 'all' as their preference.

I can do this through triggers for each of the preference options table. On `INSERT` I can also `UPDATE` the user preference array and append the new options. I am worried about performance when the user list begins to grow since each preference option may be updated and each user can have multiple preferences.

```
USER_1
  PREFERENCE_1
    OPTION_1 -> ALL
    OPTION_2 -> [1, 2, 3]
    OPTION_3 -> [1, 2]
  PREFERENCE_2
    OPTION_1 -> ALL
    OPTION_2 -> ALL
    OPTION_3 -> ALL
```

How should I design the schema to accommodate dynamic column arrays? Or perhaps I shouldn't be using arrays at all?

Additional question:

- Is it possible to achieve the *All but x* selection? A user may want all of the options but not some of the options. The selection should still grow dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your question isn't getting much love around here.

You have a couple of options.  The best option is to build out the relational tables to store this, but you will need to use a trigger or another indicator column to denote that a `user` is up for every `option`.

A second option that I have used a number of times is a `bitstring`.  This is essentially a bitmask.  The only regret I have about using this is having to explain how it works to developers fresh out of some shake-and-bake correspondence course who fancy themselves "full-stack."

```
create table preference (
  bitmask bit(30) not null primary key, -- Adjust size to some overkill number
  pref_name text
);

insert into preference 
select ((2^n)::bigint)::bit(30) as bitmask,
       'Option '||(n+1)::text as pref_name
  from generate_series(0, 10, 1) as gs(n);

create table prefs_user (
  id int primary key,
  user_name text,
  user_prefs bit(30)
);

insert into prefs_user values 
  (1, 'me', ~(0::bit(30))), 
  (2, 'you', 22::bit(30)),
  (3, 'him', ~(8::bit(30)));  -- all except Option 4
```

To join to see which options are enabled for a `prefs_user`:

```
select * 
  from prefs_user u 
  join preference p 
    on (u.user_prefs & p.bitmask)::bigint > 0 
 order by u.id, p.bitmask;

 id | user_name |           user_prefs           |            bitmask             | pref_name 
----+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000000000001 | Option 1
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000000000010 | Option 2
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000000000100 | Option 3
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000000001000 | Option 4
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000000010000 | Option 5
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000000100000 | Option 6
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000001000000 | Option 7
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000010000000 | Option 8
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000000100000000 | Option 9
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000001000000000 | Option 10
  1 | me        | 111111111111111111111111111111 | 000000000000000000010000000000 | Option 11
  2 | you       | 000000000000000000000000010110 | 000000000000000000000000000010 | Option 2
  2 | you       | 000000000000000000000000010110 | 000000000000000000000000000100 | Option 3
  2 | you       | 000000000000000000000000010110 | 000000000000000000000000010000 | Option 5
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000000000000001 | Option 1
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000000000000010 | Option 2
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000000000000100 | Option 3
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000000000010000 | Option 5
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000000000100000 | Option 6
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000000001000000 | Option 7
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000000010000000 | Option 8
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000000100000000 | Option 9
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000001000000000 | Option 10
  3 | him       | 111111111111111111111111110111 | 000000000000000000010000000000 | Option 11
```

User `me` selected all options, so any options you add up to a count of 30 will always be selected.

User `you` selected only three options.  Adding options will not affect the user's selection.

User `him` selected every option except option `4`.  New options will be selected for this user.

The `bit` string maps easily to an array from a checkbox group with `name` properties set to log-base-2 of the `bitmask`:

```
select log(2, bitmask::bigint)::int, pref_name from preference;
 
 log | pref_name 
-----+-----------
   0 | Option 1
   1 | Option 2
   2 | Option 3
   3 | Option 4
   4 | Option 5
   5 | Option 6
   6 | Option 7
   7 | Option 8
   8 | Option 9
   9 | Option 10
  10 | Option 11
(11 rows)
```

When the `post` comes in, you can create the bitmap value through a simple loop or list comprehension on the host language side.

Comment: The 2nd approach is pretty interesting. For the first approach, it does seem like I am working with two concepts: whitelisting and blacklisting. So an extra column to denote that the user preference *should* grow will be necessary.

I don't expect preference options to grow too big or quickly, so both would work. Thanks!